# How can I use multiple datasets in a singular report pane in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am simply trying to accomplish using a few views in separate tables, but within the same report. I could be fundamentally doing something wrong, but whenever I add a new table, it only allows me to pick values from the first dataset that I created. I have added a second one, but I am unable to figure out how to actually put it into another table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to set the `DatasetName` property of each table to use the corresponding Dataset you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is a duplicate question and can be found [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954642/use-two-different-datasets-in-single-report)

You can reference other datasets in one table by defining the dataset name.

```
=First(Fields!fieldname.Value,"DataSet1")
```

Reply to comment- Click on the table that you want, and go to the properties, look at the DataSetName and select the name of the dataset you want.
[image: Table Properties]

Comment: This isn't really a comprehensive walkthrough. I don't even see where you would plug in a different dataset into a table. 

I'm also not trying to merge multiple datasets into a singular table. Just 2 sets - in 2 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the report isn't list based, you can simply have two tables powered by two different datasets next to each other in the report body.

If it's list based, your report body is fixed to the main dataset associated to the list. You can get data from other datasets into there using lookup/lookupset/aggregate functions, but only really as single values (or as a list from lookupset).

It sounds like you're trying to insert a table into a list which is already there - does it need to be list based?